# Getting unique objects from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "places": "NEW YORK",
    "locations": "USA"
  },
  {
    "places": "MONTREAL",
    "locations": "QUEBEC",
    "country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "places": "MONTREAL",
    "locations": "QUEBEC",
    "country": "Canada"
  }
]
```

I want to filter and get only the unique entries. I tried the following function, but it doesn´t work:

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

Using a `Set` didn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to deep compare.  Unique instances of Objects (even if they have the exact same property values) won't be considered equal.

Comment: You should provide your definition of unique.

Comment: Why is the property `country` missing in the first object? Is it a mistake?

Comment: It´s not a mistake, some objects got two keys, others got three.

Comment: Ideally, when mapping in the first case, I would like to return only the first two objects

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution using `new Set()`.

```js
const data = [
            {
                "places": "NEW YORK",
                "locations": "USA"
            },
            {
                "places": "MONTREAL",
                "locations": "QUEBEC",
                "country": "Canada"
            },
  {
                "places": "MONTREAL",
                "locations": "QUEBEC",
                "country": "Canada"
            },

        ];
        
const uniqueArray = a => [...new Set(a.map(o => JSON.stringify(o)))].map(s => JSON.parse(s));

console.log(uniqueArray(data));
```

Comment: I was thinking on something similar using `JSON.stringify()`, but what would happen if you have two objects that have same pairs of `(key, value)` but they are presented in different order when you `stringify` they?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
let data = data.filter(function (a) {
    let key = a.places + '|' + a.country;
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = true;
        return true;
    }
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? (Also I think you're going to get an "identifier already declared error for `let data = data.filter(...`)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using underscore, you can some thing like this :

```js
var list = [
  {
    "places": "NEW YORK",
    "locations": "USA"
  },
  {
    "places": "MONTREAL",
    "locations": "QUEBEC",
    "country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "places": "MONTREAL",
    "locations": "QUEBEC",
    "country": "Canada"
  },

];

var uniqList = _.uniq(list, function (item) {
 return item.places+'_'+item.locations+'_'+item.country;
});

console.log(uniqList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

You can use `filter` with a local `Set` object. By comparing the stringified objects and the `size` property before and after trying to add to the `Set`, you can return a unique array by asking if the two numbers are not equal.

---

### Code:

```
place_array.filter(v => b.size != b.add(JSON.stringify(v)).size, b = new Set());
```

---

### Why use this code?

Unlike many of the other answers it relies on a singular pass through the array using the filter iterator. This means that it's more performant than multiple loops through an array. It also uses only localized variables, meaning that their is no global clutter and, since the `filter` method is functional, absolutely no side effects.

**Note:** *There is always a hit to performance when using a `Set` Object in any situation.* This comes down to Browser internals, however, when finding unique Objects/Arrays the `stringify` into a `Set` method is likely the best solution. Though with incredibly small data-sets you may find it practical to use an Array or build your own task-specific Object.

### Working Example:

```js
let place_array = [{
    "places": "NEW YORK",
    "locations": "USA"
  },
  {
    "places": "MONTREAL",
    "locations": "QUEBEC",
    "country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "places": "MONTREAL",
    "locations": "QUEBEC",
    "country": "Canada"
  },

];

let result = place_array.filter(v => b.size != b.add(JSON.stringify(v)).size, b = new Set());

console.log(result);
```

---

---

### Alternative Solution:

You can use `filter` with a local `Array` object. By determining whether or not the stringified objects are in the Array already and pushing if they're not, you can return a unique array by asking if the stringified object is not included in the array.

### Code:

```
place_array.filter(v => !b.includes(s(v)) && !!b.push(s(v)), s = JSON.stringify, b = []);
```

### Why use this code?

Effective though the `Set` object may be, it is ultimately slower due to backend processes than utilizing an `Array` object. You can prove this quite easily by running a test like a jsperf: https://jsperf.com/set-vs-ray-includes-battle/1

### The Results of a Test:

[image: Test Results Proving Array is Faster than Set]

### Working Example:

```js
let place_array = [{
    "places": "NEW YORK",
    "locations": "USA"
  },
  {
    "places": "MONTREAL",
    "locations": "QUEBEC",
    "country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "places": "MONTREAL",
    "locations": "QUEBEC",
    "country": "Canada"
  },

];

let result = place_array.filter(v => !b.includes(s(v)) && !!b.push(s(v)), s = JSON.stringify, b = []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @David I updated my answer with an alternative solution that utilizes `Array.prototype.includes` and is much faster, while still maintaining all the benefits of the `Set` method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 var distObj = {};
 for(let i = 0; i < obj.places.lenght; i++){
    let tmp = obj.places;
    distObj[i].places = obj[i].places.filter(item => item !== tmp);
 }
```

If you combine this with for( k in Obj) and callback you can iterate over every deep and attr in Object

Answer (score 0):

If your key values are simple as in your example, then you could do something like the following to handle instances where objects in your array have the same keys and values but not in the same order (since [object property order is not guaranteed across browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)).

- Convert objects to arrays using `Object.entries`, sort, and convert to strings with `JSON.stringify`
- Remove duplicates with `Set` and convert strings back to arrays using `JSON.parse` and then to objects using `reduce` to convert array pairs to object key value pairs

```js
const arr = [{ "places": "NEW YORK", "locations": "USA" }, { "places": "MONTREAL", "locations": "QUEBEC", "country": "Canada" }, { "country": "Canada", "places": "MONTREAL", "locations": "QUEBEC" }];
const strings = arr.map((obj) => JSON.stringify(Object.entries(obj).sort()));
const result = [...new Set(strings)].map((s) => {
  return JSON.parse(s).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    acc[k] = v;
    return acc;
  }, {});
});

console.log(result);
// [{"locations":"USA","places":"NEW YORK"},{"country":"Canada","locations":"QUEBEC","places":"MONTREAL"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
let uniqueObjects= [];
objects.map(item => {
    let exists = uniqueProperties.some((object)=>{
        // Do check here
        return object.type == item.type;
    })
    if (!exists) {
        uniqueObjects.push(item);
    }
})
```